# How to test for methods in a enum class? why is my code for testing not triggering the methods mentioned?

Tags: java, junit5

I'm trying to mock the class and call the methods using that, but for some reason the methods are not being initiated.

The class to be tested

```
public enum Square {    
    
    SQUARE_SET(3);
    private final int a;

    Square(int l) {
        this.a = l*l;
    }
     
    public int getSquare() {
        return a;
    }//can not trigger this method

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Area :");
        sb.append(a);
        return sb.toString();
    }//can not trigger this method
}
```

My code for testing the above class

```
class SquareTest {

    int l;
    private int a;

    @Test
    void testGetSquare() {
        Square Square = mock(Square.class);
        assertEquals(a, Square.getSquare());
    }

    void testToString() {
        Square Square = mock(Square.class);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Area :");
        sb.append(a);
        sb.toString();
        when(Square.toString()).thenReturn(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: That's not how unit testing works! You don't mock the class that you're testing. You mock dependencies that are required by the class you're testing.

Comment: your tests are bogus. you mock what you are testing, meaning you are not actually testing it.

Comment: Your `Square` file won't compile. You appear to be confused about what `enum`s are. That looks like it should just be a `class`. And, as said in other comments, you don't mock the class under test, you mock the dependencies.

Comment: Just to clarify, once you've resolved your class/enum issue, the line `Square Square = mock(Square.class);` should be changed to `Square Square = new Square(someNumber);`